# how to extract ipaddress,date&time,http:// in a log file using java

Tags: java

if my logfile contains various lines like
sample data:/* 10.1.5.121 - d31f [17/Sep/2014:07:00:04 +0530] "POST http://webres3.qheal.ctmail.com/SpamResolverNG/SpamResolverNG.dll?DoNewRequest HTTP/1.0" 200 164 "HTTP" ""/*
how to extract ipaddress,date&time,http://... alone using Stringtokenizer concept.

Comment: Can you precise a little bit what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Using array, list, hashtable or any collections data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    String word = "abc,catch,profile";
    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error  " + e);
    }

    // now read the file line by line
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(word, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if (line.contains(st.nextToken())) {
                System.out.println(line);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    scanner.close();`
```

Comment: THIS CODE WORKS FINE... use string tokenizer and split into tokens and o/p to a file..if that file is used as input this code works GR8.

Comment: PLZ HELP ME WITH CODE FOR ABOVE REQUIREMENT.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications in the previous Code of mine.. Hope this will work for You..

```
File file = new File("FileTest.txt");
    String[] findMe = {"abc","profile","catch"};
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
           e.printStackTrace();
    }


    int i=1;
    ArrayList<String> neededLines = new ArrayList<String>();


    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        for (String string : findMe) {
            if(line.contains(string)){
                if(!neededLines.contains(line))
                    neededLines.add(line);                  
            }
        }       
    }
    System.out.println(neededLines);
```

Comment: Thanks sonal...code doesnt give expected results

Comment: Hi Aiswarya, I have made some changes, Hope this will help..